# Unable to Translate Keys using Ng2-Translate in Http Interceptors and Home Component Angular 2 , Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, ng2-translate

My Code is like below, I am using 3rd party login (openAM) for my application. when ever I got 401, I should redirect the application to another URL from there user will be logged in.

I user http interceptors to check the status and redirect to login. 
Question1: Is this approach is correct ?

Question2: Translations are not happening.

check **handleHttpResponseCodes** method. In that "unauthorisedMessage" is not translating. Not only that any message is not translating. is anything wrong with my code.

---

```js
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { AuthService } from 'app/blocks/auth/auth.service';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';
import { AlertService } from '../../core/services/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as jsToaster from 'toastr';

@Injectable()
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private injector: Injector,
        private router: Router,
        private translate: TranslateService
    ) {}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {

        // console.log(req);
        if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
            // check to see if there's internet
            // if there is no internet, throw a HttpErrorResponse error
            // since an error is thrown, the function will terminate here
            return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse({
                error: 'NO_INTERNET'
            }));
        } else {
            // else return the normal request
            return this.handleResponse(next, req);
        }
    }
    handleResponse(next, req) {
        return next.handle(req)
            .do((ev: HttpEvent < any > ) => {
                if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    //console.log('ev in the do: ', ev);
                }
            })
            .catch((response: any) => {
                if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    this.handleHttpResponseCodes(response);
                } else {
                    console.log('::UNKNOWN ERROR::', response);
                }
                return Observable.throw(response);
            });
    }
    handleHttpResponseCodes(exception) {
        let authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
        let translate = this.injector.get(TranslateService);
        let alertService = this.injector.get(AlertService);
        const router = this.injector.get(Router);


        switch (exception.status) {
            case 401: //UNAUTHORIZED
                debugger;
                this.translate.get('unauthorisedMessage').subscribe((res: string) => {
                    debugger;
                   **//ISSUE: TRANSLATION NOT HAPPENING WHY? //**
                    this.showToast(res, '401'); 
                });

                setTimeout(() => {
                    authService.login_openAM();
                }, 3000);

                break;
            case 400: //BAD REQUEST OR FR SESSION TIME OUT

                this.translate.get('loginSessionExpiredMessage').subscribe((res: string) => {
                    debugger;
                    this.showToast(res, '400');
                });

                setTimeout(() => {
                    authService.loginSessionExpired();
                }, 2000);

                break;
            case 403: // FORBIDDED ACCESS
                //TODO
                break;
            case 502: // BAD GATEWAY

                break;
            case 503: //SERVICE UNAVAILABLE
                jsToaster.error("SERVICE UNAVAILABLE", "503");
                break;
            case 504: //GATEWAY TIMEOUT
                jsToaster.error("SERVICE UNAVAILABLE", "CODE:504-GATEWAY TIMEOUT");
                break;
        }
        console.log(':Service Exception::', exception);
    }

    showToast(title, body, typeOfToast, waitTime) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            jsToaster[typeOfToast](body, title);
        }, waitTime);
    }

}
```

**AppLoadService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { APP_SETTINGS } from 'app/app-settings/settings';
import { AlertService } from '../core/services/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppLoadService {

    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private alertService: AlertService
    ) { }


    load(): Promise<any> {
        console.log('@started step1');
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const promise = this.httpClient.get('assets/settings/config.json') // CONTAINS APPLICATION LOGIN AND LOGOUT URL PATHS
                .subscribe(
                    res_config => {
                        console.log('@config json loaded step2');
                        APP_SETTINGS.app_login_url = res_config["app_login_url"] || res_config["app_LOGIN_URL"];
                        APP_SETTINGS.app_logout_url = res_config["app_logout_url"] || res_config["app_LOGOUT_URL"];
                        console.log("::initializeApp:config file loaded");
                        /*=========== AUTH API - START ===========*/
                        this.httpClient.get('/XXXX/v2/authentication-api') 
                            .subscribe(
                                res_auth_context => {
                                    this.storeUserContext(res_auth_context);
                                    console.log('@auth context loaded step3');

                                    /*=========== LOAD PRODUCTS ===========*/
                                    this.httpClient.get('/XXXX/v1/api/lab')
                                        .subscribe(
                                            res_products => {
                                                console.log('@auth context loaded step4');
                                                APP_SETTINGS.isproductsLoaded = true;
                                                APP_SETTINGS.appproducts = res_products;
                                                console.log("::initializeApp:: products Loaded");
                                                resolve();
                                            },
                                            res_products_error => {
                                                console.log("::initializeApp:: products NOT Loaded", res_products_error);
                                                resolve();
                                            }
                                        );
                                    /*=========== LOAD products ===========*/
                                },
                                res_auth_context_error => {
                                    console.log("Auth Call Failed");
                                }
                            );
                        /*=========== AUTH CONTEXT CALL API - END ===========*/

                    },
                    res_config_Error => {
                        console.log("::initializeApp:config file NOT  loaded", res_config_Error);
                    }
                );
        });
    }

    storeUserContext(usetContext: any): any {
        sessionStorage.setItem("AUTH_TOKEN", JSON.stringify(usetContext));
    }

}
```

**APP MODULE**

```js
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json');
}


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, CustomDateRangePickerComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        // :CORE MODULE: //
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(
            {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [Http]
            }),
        FormsModule,
        CommonModule, //<====added

        //:3RD PARTY MODULE://
        BootstrapModalModule,

        //:APPLICTION MODULES: //
        AppLoadModule, //Startupdata before APP loaded
        AppRoutingModule,
        FooterModule,
        ErrorModule,
        AccessDeniedModule,
        NotFoundModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
        ToasterModule.forChild(),
    ],
    providers: [
        LoaderService,
        ToasterService,
        StartupService,
        ResponseStatusesService,
        LocalStorageService,
        ApplicationSettingsService,
        LabSelectionService,
        AccountService,
        AuthService,
        AlertService,
        AuthGuard,
        RolesGuard,
        FeaturebasedGuard,
        ErrorLogService,
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            useClass: GlobalErrorsHandler
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AppHttpInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: LocationStrategy,
            useClass: HashLocationStrategy
        },
    ],
    exports: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**Home Component**

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService, private translate: TranslateService,
    private router: Router,
    private AuthService: AuthService,
    private AlertService: AlertService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {   
    if (this.AuthService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      let userDetails = this.AuthService.getUserDetails();
      if (userDetails) {
        let redirect_path = this.routeResolver(userDetails);
        //=>ROUTE TO REDIRECT BASED ON LOGGED IN USER ROLE<=//
        this.router.navigate([redirect_path]);
      } else {
        this.AlertService.error("invalidUserDetailsRecieved", "home comp");
      }
    }
  }
```

**Alert Service (I am using angular2 toaster)**

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Fault } from "../../models/fault";
import { ToasterService, Toast } from "angular2-toaster";
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from "ng2-translate";

@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
  constructor(
    private toastyService: ToasterService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
  ) { }

  success(title: string, message: string): void {
    this.translate.get([title, message]).subscribe(res => {
      this.showToast(res[title], res[message], "success");
    });
  }

  info(title: string, message: string): void {
    this.translate.get([title, message]).subscribe(res => {
      this.showToast(res[title], res[message], "info");
    });
  }

  warning(title: string, message: string): void {
    let toastBlock = () => {
      this.translate.get([title, message]).subscribe(res => {
        this.showToast(res[title], res[message], "warning");
      });
    }
    this.triggerToastWithMessage(toastBlock);
  }

  error(title: string, message: string): void {
    let toastBlock = () => {
      this.translate.get([title, message]).subscribe(res => {
        this.showToast(res[title], res[message], "error");
      });
    }
    this.triggerToastWithMessage(toastBlock);
  }

  fault(fault: Fault): void {
    this.showToast("", fault.message, "error");
  }

  showToast(title, body, type) {
    var toast: Toast = <Toast>{
      title: title,
      body: body,
      type: type
    };
    this.toastyService.pop(toast);
  }

  triggerToastWithMessage(fn) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fn();
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
            { path: 'error', loadChildren: './core/error/error.module#ErrorModule' },
            { path: 'accessDenied', loadChildren: './accessDenied/access-denied.module#AccessDeniedModule' },
            { path: 'notfound', loadChildren: './notFound/not-found.module#NotFoundModule' },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound' }
        ]
    }

];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**HomeRoutingModule**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'job-search',
        loadChildren: '../job-search/job-search.module#JobSearchModule',
        canActivate: [RolesGuard],
        data: {
          roles: permitted_roles.JOB_SEARCH,
          router_name: routerNames.JOB_SEARCH,
        }
      },
      
      -------------
      -------------
```

**AuthGaurd**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private AuthService: AuthService,
    private AlertService: AlertService,
    private ResponseStatusesService: ResponseStatusesService
  ) {
    console.log('AuthGuard Constructor Executed');
  }


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log("Authgaurd can activate");
    if (this.AuthService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      debugger;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

```js
Auth Service

public isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("AUTH_TOKEN");
    if (token) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, try explicitly using the locale code :

```
this.translate.use('en-EN');
```

Comment: I dont want to Hard Code.

Comment: It is just an example. Does your application use multiple languages? If yes, then apply the previous example with the corresponding ISO code of your current locale. If not then you can juste pass it like this. See the official doc here https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you were on the right way.
But interceptor should be like that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable<any>) => {
        switch(err.status){
         case 404:
          return throwError('Errors.404');
        default:
          return throwError('Errors.500')
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

On this implementation, you will just throw back the ***localization token*** of error.

On `subscription` you should handle such errors:

```
.subscribe((result: any) => {
    ... success result here ...
}, error => {
  this.error = error;  <--- this what you need
});
```

And on `HTML` template just use `translate` pipe for localization:

```
<div>{{error|translate}}</div>
```

Here is a [working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xdt2bu)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I saw your example. You are calling an API inside app component itself and catching the error and displaying in App component.html but my scenario is , I need to call an API , first, to know the user is authenticated. So, I am using appload service and calling that before app loads. see my latest edit.

Comment: it doesn't matter, I've just shown you how to handle errors with translations

Comment: Spike, I am just using a java script toaster which will accept "text" as input. I am not in any page by the time my service responds with 401 or any other , because I am calling a service which executes before the app loads. So , I dont have any place to write the code <div>{{error|translate}}</div>. Pls let me know if you need more information

Comment: can you check once

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set up the translate service and provide the interceptor correctly. This is what works for me:

```ts
// app.module.ts

@NgModule({
  providers: [{ 
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
    useClass: AppHttpInterceptor, 
    multi: true, 
    deps: [ AuthService, TranslateService, AlertService, Router ] 
  }],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(translateService: TranslateService, localStorage: LocalStorageService) {

    translateService.addLangs(SUPPORTED_LANGS);
    translateService.setDefaultLang(DEFAULT_LANG);

    // Use either the lang stored in browser local storage... 
    const useLang: string = localStorage.getLang()
      // ...the browser language if supported...
      || SUPPORTED_LANGS.find(lang => lang === translate.getBrowserLang())
      // ...or the default language
      || DEFAULT_LANG;

    translate.use(useLang)
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.componentActive), switchMap(() => translate.onLangChange))
      // Update the local storage on language change
      .subscribe((e: TranslationChangeEvent) => localStorage.setLang(e.lang));
  }
  // ...
}
```

```ts
// app-http.interceptor.ts

export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private translateService: TranslateService,
              private alertService: AlertService,
              private router: Router) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Hope this helps a little :-)